# IN clause for multiple columns on the same value set

Tags: postgresql

I have a `WHERE` clause like below:

```sql
WHERE t1.col1 IN ('a', 'b', 'c') OR t2.col2 IN ('a', 'b', 'c');
```

I know that the two `IN` clauses will always have the same contents. Is there any way I can avoid duplicating them?

Something like:

```sql
WHERE (t1.col1 OR t2.col2) IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the array [overlaps](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html) operator:

```
where array[t1.col1, t2.col2] && array['a','b','c']
```

Comment: But note that indexes on `col1` and `col2` (if any) will not be used.

Answer (score 1):

```
with flt(x) as (values('{a,b,c}'::text[]))
select
...
from ..., flt
where t1.col1 = any(flt.x) or t2.col2 = any(flt.x);
```

There are two ways to use some constant values in the PostgreSQL. Using CTE as shown above. Or using "options":

```
set foo.bar to '{a,b,c}';
select '{c,d,e}'::text[] && current_setting('foo.bar')::text[];
```